# Exclude specific category from Related Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Looking to exclude specific category (ID = 100) from "Related Posts" feed at bottom of Blog pages. Extra bonus if it can also exclude from the sidebar archive (not sure if they are connected??)

I'm using WP Theme "TheFox", have asked them - not part of their theme.

I "think" it has to do in the functions.php. I have found some similar questions, and code, but have not had any luck.

I'm a complete noob for .php, so be gentle :)

I've found some other attempts, no luck. Not registering or effecting the feed.

```
$categories_to_exclude [ 100 ];
$first_cat  = false; 
$categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
while ( ! empty( $categories ) && false === $first_cat ) {
 if ( in_array($categories[0]->cat_ID, $categories_to_exclude) ) {
  array_shift($categories);
 }
   else {
       $first_cat = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I could gather from your question is that You want to ignore one category (may be more) in the related post query?

use the following CODE (some explanation is given within the CODE in comments):

`// set the category ID (or multiple category IDs)
    // you want to ignore in the following array
    $cats_to_ignore = array( 2 );
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() );
    $category_in = array_diff( $categories, $cats_to_ignore );
    // ignore only if we have any category left after ignoring
    if( count( $category_in ) == 0 ) {
        $category_in = $categories;
    }
    $cat_args = array(
        'category__in'   => $category_in,
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'post__not_in'   => array( get_the_ID() )
        );
    $cat_query = new WP_Query( $cat_args );
    while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();
        /* just example markup for related posts */
        echo '<h2><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>';
    endwhile;
    // reset $post after custom loop ends (if you need the main loop after this point)
    wp_reset_postdata();`

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes that is what I'm looking for. To confirm, I add this in to the functions.php? And to match with my IDs, I adjust the  = array( 2 ); to my ID number.

Comment: yeah, you need to paste this code in functions.php, and you need to replace array( 2 ); with category ID you want to ignore.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working. It adds in the H2 titles as text, across the top of everypage - above the navigation. I only want it to adjust the "Related Posts" on bottom of blog posts. 

I added it in the functions.php through Theme Editor.

What am I missing? I can't leave it in to share the code as it is a live site.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, it must work

```
    $categories_to_exclude [ 81, 11, 21 ];
$first_cat  = false; 
$categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
while ( ! empty( $categories ) && false === $first_cat ) {
   if ( in_array($categories[0]->cat_ID, $categories_to_exclude) ) {
      array_shift($categories);
   }
   else {
       $first_cat = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
   }
}
```

You get the categories with get_the_category. Then in the while loop you skip the first category if it's 81, and look again. If it's not 81 (and you still have categories available), you asign it to $first_cat and carry on.